# Intricacies in Python's parser

Tags: python

In what order are the contents of the expression`"word" in [] == False` parsed? It seems to defy all logic:

```
>>> "word" in [] == False
False
>>> ("word" in []) == False
True
>>> "word" in ([] == False)
TypeError
```

How does Python actually interpret this expression, and why does it interpret it so?

Edit:

the most general case seems to be

```
>>> any_value in any_list == any_symbol_or_value
False
```

Comment: Don't compare to `True` or `False` without an exceptionally good reason. The equivalent goes for every language, not just Python. Adding more code doesn't always make things more clear, or even more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word in []` is short-circuiting the first expression due to an implicit `and`.  When it realizes that it's false, it stops evaluating the rest of the expression, which is a comparison between `[]` (the same entity that `word` was just testing against) and the value `False`.  `[]` does not equal `False`, so the implicit "and" expression is false.

`("word" in []) == False` works as expected because `( )` makes the sub-clause finish and have its *result* compared to `False`.

Of course, once again, `[]` does not equal `False`.

---

To clarify the first case, you might test it like this:

```
foo = []

if ("word" in foo) and (foo == False):
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

This is, functionally, what's going on.

Comment: `[]` does not *equal* `False` (`==`), but `[]` *is* `False` such that `bool([])` is `False`, as guaranteed by the language.  (Which does not complicate this OP's example, but at the very least makes some of your response incomplete or ambiguous.)

Comment: That's true, but using your logic you could also legitimately say that `"1"` is the same as `1` because `int("1") == 1` is `True`, as guaranteed by the language.  `[]` is just as different from `False` as `"1"` is different from `1`.  Remember that Python is dynamically but *strongly* typed.

Comment: @syrion: Except that you don't *have* to use the explicit conversion (I just did that to make it clear).  If you do `foo = []; if foo:`, that evaluates as if `foo` were false - this is a *very* important part of how (empty) containers work.  `"1"` will never be implicitly cast to an integer, while containers WILL be implicitly cast to boolean all the time.

Comment: Isn't that because the `if foo` statement is doing an implicit cast to `bool()`, though?  I always thought of this as un-Pythonic (explicit over implicit) and try to write `if foo == []:` (or as appropriate) instead, to avoid the implicit cast in case it would be less clear.

Comment: Well right, that's why I say this is a very important thing to point out - Python simply doesn't *do* implicit conversions, *except* to boolean.  The reality is it *has* to do this - you're always going to want to write the very natural expression `if <thing>:` to test if `thing` actually exists - it's just a very specific design decision that empty containers should evaluate to `False` instead of having an `.empty()` method (as C++ does).

Comment: (Also, for hopeless inside baseball, containers aren't actually coalesced directly to `bool`, as many (all?) don't even have a `__bool__` method - they logically evaluate to `False` because it falls back to `__len__` which is `0`.  However, the mechanics aside, it is intended by design that empty containers are logically `False`.)

Comment: PEP 8 does say to compare to singletons using `is` and `is not`.  That's not Gospel, or anything, of course, but it is notable.  In this case, I still think the `bool()` cast is missing the forest for the trees; `[]` is still not going to evaluate to `False` inside a comparison that doesn't do this implicit conversion.

Comment: What I think I'm getting from this is that `word in [] == False` is equivalent to `(word in []) and ([] == False)`, because it's fed to the same preprocessing logic that makes `x < y < z` work. Is that correct?

Answer (score 10):

Normally you can find out operator precedence with [this table.](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary).

But this is actually a tricky example:

> Comparisons can be chained
>   arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is
>   equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except
>   that y is evaluated only once (but in
>   both cases z is not evaluated at all
>   when x < y is found to be false).

[See the notes on comparisons.](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin)

So `"word" in [] == False` is really

```
("word" in []) and ([] == False)
```

where the two `[]` are actually the same object.

This is useful for other comparisons, ie `0 < a < 10`, but really confusing here!

Comment: This is the more correct answer and was given much earlier than syrion's answer

Comment: Both answers were edited after their initial submission.  When I submitted mine, this one said "You can find out using this table. In this case you can see that all the operators involved have the same precedence, the expression is simply evaluates left to right."

Comment: @gnibbler i generally dislike it when people initially give a short, vague answer in order to chronologically secure themselves and afterwards edit it to provide a somewhat acceptable answer so that people like you will naively accept that answer based on chronology.

Comment: @ppalka: I just didn't get the question when i first read it, so I had to edit my answer.